# Matlab ,How to get elements in a matrix using two arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

For example, I have a matrix like `A=[1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8;9,10,11,12]`. And two array `x=[1,1,3,2]` and `y = [2,4,3,1]`, which represent X- and Y-coordinate.

And I want to get 4 elements in the matrix  `[A(1,2);A(1,4);A(3,3);A(2,1)]`. I use this code: `result = diag(A(x,y));` Although I get what I want, but if I deal with a large matrix, such code runs too slow for me. Dose someone have a better way?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)

```
A = [1,2,3,4; 
     5,6,7,8;
     9,10,11,12];
x = [1,1,3,2];
y = [2,4,3,1];
id = sub2ind(size(A),x,y)
id =
    4   10    9    2
A(id)
ans =
    2    4   11    5
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the faster ones, but following are some approaches to this:

```
A = [1  2  3  4;
     5  6  7  8;
     9 10 11 12];

x = [1  1  3  2];
y = [2  4  3  1];

%Approach-1 (Yours approach)
diagonal = diag(A(x,y))

%Approach-2
A1=A(x,y);   LowUp=A1(tril(triu(A1))~=0)

%Approach-3
EYE= A1((eye(4,4).*A1)~=0)

%Approach-4
findeye=A1(find(eye(size(A1))))

%Approach-5
subind=A(sub2ind(size(A),x,y)).'

%Approach-6
for i=1:4
    loop(i)=A(x(i),y(i));
end
loop=loop.'
```